# How do I access the logged in user object in a view?

Tags: node.js, pug, passport.js, koa, koa-passport

Once a user has been logged in, how do I reference `this.req.user` from inside of a view?

I think this would involve updating the locals collection of the Jade middleware. I haven't been able to get a reference to this object though.

Up until now I've been doing the following...

```
app.use(jade.middleware({
    viewPath: __dirname + '/views',
    debug: true,
    pretty: true,
    compileDebug: true,
    locals: {
        moment: require('moment'),
        _: require('lodash')
    }
}));
```

And then in the view there'd be something like this...

```
span=moment(new Date(item.date)).calendar()
```

Of course now I have a user object that cannot be assigned at set-up.

Comment: Can you post the code containing your res.render() call

Comment: Which one? I'm not sure of the relevance. The logged in user needs to be in place for all routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few libraries you could use, here is how you would do it with [co-views](https://github.com/tj/co-views):

```
'use strict';
let koa     = require('koa'),
    views   = require('co-views');

let app = koa();

let render = views(__dirname + '/jade/', {default: 'jade'});

app.use(function *controller(){
  let data;

  data = {
    user: this.req.user
  };

  this.body = yield render('jadeFileName', data);
});
```

I made a screencast on serving content from Koa with Jade which might be helpful.  You can find it at:

http://knowthen.com/episode-6-serving-content-in-koajs-with-jade/

**EDIT:**

Here is an option in response to your desire to not pass the user when calling render.

```
'use strict';
let koa     = require('koa'),
    views   = require('co-views');

let app = koa();

let render = views(__dirname + '/jade/', {default: 'jade'});

// using custom middleware
app.use(function *(next){
  this.render = function (fileName, data){
    data = data || {};
    data.user = this.req.user;
    return render(fileName, data);
  }
  yield next;
});

app.use(function *controller(){      
  this.body = yield this.render('jadeFileName');
});
```

Comment: But then I need to pass the user with every render.

Comment: Good idea. I've updated your answer because it didn't quite work.

Comment: Namely... a reference needed to be saved for the default render and the default render needed to be called on 'this'. The new version needed the correct signature and needed to be a generator. Also I added in the check for IsAuthenticated because I was already doing that. Seems like a good idea to do both in one custom middleware.

Answer (score 0):

In your express configuration, you need to store the user object in res.locals after you authenticate the user, something like this works:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.locals.user = req.user;
  next();
});
```

Then you should be able to reference the user in your jade templates:

```
block content
  p= user.email
```

Comment: aha... but this is koa.

Comment: Have you looked at the koa-locals module?  https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-locals

Comment: Check out the example given here https://github.com/koa-modules/koa-locals/blob/master/example/app.js

Comment: Can you post the code of you setting the locals object, and the part where you call it inside your view?